# Python find method doesn't work as expected

Tags: python

I am looking for string data that I read from another file within the string I read from one file.

```
import json
with open('basliklar.json', 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
    datab = file.read().replace('\n', '')
    basliklar_arr=json.loads(datab)
with open('icerikler.json', 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
    datai = file.read().replace('\n', '')
    icerikler_arr=json.loads(datai)
t=icerikler_arr[10].find(basliklar_arr[16]['text'])

print(t)
```

Problem right there. 'string'.find() method return -1.But i tried following line its working.

```
t=icerikler_arr[10].find('same value from file')
```

I guess problem is encode but i cant solve.

Files

icerikler.json

```
[" (Değişik: 21\/2\/2001 -4630\/1 md.) \r\n\r\n şehircilik tasarım ve projeleri, mimari maketler, endüstri, çevre ve sahne tasarım ve projeleri. \r\n\r\n (Ek: 7\/6\/1995 - 4110\/1 md.) Arayüzüne temel oluşturan düşünce ve ilkeleri de içine almak üzere, bir bilgisayar \r\n\r\nprogramının herhangi bir ögesine temel oluşturan düşünce ve ilkeler eser sayılmazlar. \r\n\r\n **II – Musiki eserleri:**","..."]
```

basliklar.json

```
[{"text":" Kapsam ","no":2},{"text":" Tanımlar ","no":2},{"text":" B) Fikir ve sanat eserlerinin çeşitleri","no":2},{"text":" I – İlim ve edebiyat eserleri","no":2},{"text":" **II – Musiki eserleri** ","no":3}]
```

Comment: You don't need to remove the newlines first; `json.loads` can handle them. Just use `... = json.load(file)`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks.But this does not solve my problem :)

Comment: Can you publish the values of `icerikler_arr[10]` and `basliklar_arr[16]['text']`?

Comment: Does `t=icerikler_arr[10].find(r'same value from file')` give the same result?

Comment: Does `'same value from file' == basliklar_arr[16]['text']` return `True`? *Something* is probably different.

Comment: print(basliklar_arr[16]['text']=='II – Sahibinin adı belirtilmiyen eserlerde') // return false but its same :)

Comment: also tried print(basliklar_arr[16]['text']==r'II – Sahibinin adı belirtilmiyen eserlerde')

Comment: The problem might be at the level of the JSONs themselves - are they just arrays/lists, or more complicated nested structures?  You'd ought to post a sample of your JSONs, otherwise people may not be able to replicate the issue.

Comment: Sorry.There is a space in the last line